# Disable error checking on an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I want to totally disable error checking on a project so that no warnings or errors will show in the "Problems" tab.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the "Problems" tab, click on the little triangle (in the title bar on the right side, next to the controls for minimizing and maximizing the window), select "Configure Contents", and then you can define filters.

Comment: "Configure Contents" was not available for me.  I am running Version: 3.5.1, I right clicked the yellow triangle.

Comment: Not the yellow warning triangle, the white one (pointing down) in the title bar on the right side, next to the controls for minimizing and maximizing the window.

Comment: This works for TODO tasks also, you can configure it to use only TODO's in the selected project...wish I knew about this earlier.

Comment: This only works for "Problems" tab, leaving all error markers in code, package explorer, etc. untouched. Please take a look at my solution with disabling Java Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you create a general project rather than a Java project?

Depending on what you want I think it should also work if you disable "Build Automatically" in the Project-menu.

Comment: I tried to disable build automatically but It applied to all the projects in the workspace

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply close the project if it's one you're not working on at the moment. Closed projects aren't included in the Problems view.