# How do I get Eclipse to ignore errors in WSDL file?

Tags: eclipse, wsdl

EDIT: To be clear, I want to get rid of the big red X on my project, not just filter the errors from the "Problems" list.

I get a bunch of these errors. How do I make Eclipse ignore them? I donøt have the option of fixing the actual problem :(

> src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ser:char'. It was detected that 'ser:char' is in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///Users/itunesuser/git/online-service-wizard/suppression-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuse/multiservice/multiservice.wsdl'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'ser:char' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///Users/itunesuser/git/online-service-wizard/suppression-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuse/multiservice/multiservice.wsdl'. multiservice.wsdl   /Scrubbr-suppression-extension/src/main/resources/com/satorisoftware/ws/infuse/multiservice line 623    WSDL Problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable error checking on an eclipse project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426268/disable-error-checking-on-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: Sorry Ryan no. That only gets rid of it in the "Problems" tab. I still get a red X on my project, and that's my real problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Properties, find Validation, switch off WSDL validation entirely.

Not ideal, but better than nothing.

Comment: And probably way better than disabling wsdl validation on complete workspace. Mostly you'd only want to ignore wsdls in one of your projects.

Answer (score 16):

Go to window > preferences  search for validations(it is not under any menu) > scroll down for wsdl and uncheck the wsdl in the list see the screenshot like below.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that you may need to right click the project and select "Validate" to get Eclipse to notice that validation has been turned off and actually remove the errors. At least, that has been my experience in Neon.